# Counting record without count function

Tags: mysql, sql

Human table:

```
ID  Name
1   Peter
2   Peter
3   Peter
4   Tom
5   Tom
6   Mary
7   Paul
```

If I want to select a name which is containing 3 or more times in the human table, I can write the query like this:

```
Select name, count(name)
From Human
Group By name
Having count(name) >= 3
```

But I need to write a query without having and count function now. So, how to implement this query?

Comment: What is the use case/assignment for which you are prevented from using `COUNT()` ?

Comment: I don't understand your meaning. You mean why I don't use the count function?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean.

Comment: Er......my teacher give a extra challenge for me to implement the query without having or count function

Comment: Well, if that is an extra challenge, why not simply tell them you are not able to solve this (and ask for a hint maybe). What good does it do to ask for a solution here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
WITH cte
AS (
    SELECT NAME
        ,SUM(1) AS NameCount
    FROM Human
    GROUP BY NAME
    )
SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE NameCount >= 3
```

or

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT NAME
        ,SUM(1) AS NameCount
    FROM Human
    GROUP BY NAME
    ) MyTable
WHERE NameCount >= 3
```

Comment: MySQL doesn't support CTE, and this is still counting as far as I can tell.

Comment: sorry, I thought it is Sql Server related

Answer (score 4):

No `GROUP BY`, no `HAVING`, no `COUNT` - but a double self `join`. Doesn't make much sense, but it works!

```
select distinct t1.name
from tablename t1
join tablename t2 on t1.name = t2.name and t1.id <> t2.id
join tablename t3 on t1.name = t3.name and t1.id <> t3.id and t2.id <> t3.id
```

BTW, tell you teacher you found this solution on the Internet...

**Demo here:**

## SQLFiddle

Comment: I never would have thought of this solution +1

Comment: HaHaHa, of course I will tell my teacher the answer from internet. Thank you